# GCP internal IPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ping

I have a few GCP VM instances. When I do `gcloud compute instances list` I can see all instances. The internal IPs start with 10. and external IPs start with 35. But when I try pinging one of the prod servers using hostname (ping somehost.paymetry.ga) from a dev server (also a GCP machine) , I am getting a response from an IP address starting with 195. Ideally, there should have been no response, since the host name of the prod server is not configured in /etc/hosts of the dev server. What could be the reason for a response from a 195 address?

Comment: Can you be clearer? When you ping what from where? On public IP, private IP? How/where do you see that the IP address start with 195? Screen shot can also help!

Comment: Also, can you find this 195.x.x.x IP from the VPC network page ?    
https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/networks/list

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere , when I pinged once again to take a screenshot, I noticed something. Let us say I am pinging somehost.paymetry.ga, the response says PING paymetry.ga (195.20.48.121) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 195.20.48.121 (195.20.48.121): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=367 ms
64 bytes from 195.20.48.121 (195.20.48.121): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=367 ms
. i.e, I am pinging somehost.paymetry.ga, but the response is from paymetry.ga.

Comment: So, you aren't pinging the server by it's IP, but by it's DNS name, isn't it?

Comment: Correct. I wanted to make sure that the prod servers are mot accessible from dev server using the host name. Our database is accessed using the DNS name. Wanted to make sure accidentally connections don't end up going to prod.